# How to work out with sending sms using nexmo in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, vonage

This is the route code:

```
router.get('/compose/:ID', function(req, res, next) {
var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
console.log("random = " + random);
   res.render('compose', { random: random, Id:req.params.ID });
})
.post(function(req, res, next) {

var to = '917985754084';
var from = 'GrumpyText';
var text = req.body.OTP;

console.log(text);

nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text, function(err,success){
  if(success)
  console.log("SMS sent successfully!");
  else {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
});
```

This is the handlebar code:

```
<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>List of Contacts</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="OTP" class="form-control" value="Hi. Your OTP is : {{random}}"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
</td>
    </tr>
  </form>
  </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
</main>
```

Its coming to the route but the console is not printing the 'text'. aka `console.log(text)` means `req.body.OTP` is not printing anything. Earlier it was printing undefined.
Could you please rectify where it is stucking perhaps?

Comment: And also I am already using the body-parser package and have included them globally in app.js. So no error is coming out from the body-parser additionally.

Comment: The code you have to send the SMS looks ok, and the issue seems to be around `req.body.OTP`.  How are you sending the parameter from the app?

Comment: its already there. check route.get()

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are hitting is `body-parser` doesn't handle `multipart/form-data`.

There are several options, but one of those is [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme).

```js
\* add these for multi-part*\
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer();
\* other code *\
router
  .get('/compose/:ID', function (req, res, next) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000 + 1);
    console.log('random = ' + random);
    res.render('compose', { random: random, Id: req.params.ID });
  })
  .post('/compose/:ID', upload.none(), function (req, res, next) {
    var to = '917985754084';
    var from = 'GrumpyText';
    var text = req.body.OTP;

    nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text, function (err, success) {
      if (success) console.log('SMS sent successfully!');
      else {
        console.log('error');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Also with nexmo I am getting message: SMS sent successfully! but in actual I am not receiving any sort of message. Why? What are the exact nexmo configurations? Does that private key and secret needs necessary to be send? If yes then what to put in those place?

Comment: The success in this case is when the api call completes properly. Without logging the response from the api, there isn't any way of knowing the issue. If you initialized the Nexmo object with apikey and secret, that's all you would need to run the send SMS method.

Comment: The initial question, was this the right answer? Has it moved past that part at least?